# Unable to use the WiFi on Ubuntu

Tags: wireless, hp

I desperately need some help with my WiFi in Ubuntu. I am very new so I am not sure which info is needed to help me. Basically when I plug in my Ethernet cable my internet works but the WiFi does not work. Can't find any WiFi networks.

I use a HP ENVY x360 notebook and Ubuntu and Windows is installed on the laptop.

If you need extra info please would you explain how to get it as I am completely new with Ubuntu.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: First look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) then [edit] your question and provide the additional info there...

Comment: This one uses: Intel® 802.11ac  Wi-Fi.

Comment: To open terminal, use the keyboard shortcut, `Ctrl+Alt+t`. After the terminal opens type in the above command (given by Pilot6) then press enter.

Comment: And what is the Ubuntu version?

Answer (score 0):

I too had the similar issues. Please try following command on your Ubuntu terminal.

```
sudo rmmod acer_wmi
```

Each time you start your computer, you need to type above command. You may do following to solve the issues and you won't need to execute the above command again and again.

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist acer-wmi"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

Reboot the system. Enjoy!!